# Seeming energy paradox in quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Imagine an electron in atomic or ascillator potential - any bound electron state. The WF has bell like shape fading at infinity - where classical energy of the electron by all means greatly exceeds the state energy eigenvalue. Now, if we place a trap for the electron at this distance and finally get the electron trapped there - we will end up with the electron energy much higher than its energy eigenvalue, and this seems to violate energy conservation principle. Where is a mistake? == The following is an update regarding "leaking into the trap" model ==  WF is a complex amplitude of probability TO FIND A PARTICLE IN A SPECIFIC SPACE LOCATION. How do we measure probability? We place a trap. Good trap is the one the beast is unaware of. And it's a shutter-like device - when the shutter closes the particle is either in or out. So we activate the trap by closing shutter and find our particle trapped. Violation of energy? OR - Does it follow that closing the trap is not an energy free process? Then, closing the trap interfears with the particle state, pumping it with energy? And what do we mean then by saying probability density amplitude for WF? (we can t measure it!)

Comment: "The WF has _bell like_ shape" isn't necessarily true. All you can say is that it approaches 0 at infinity. But it can be 0 in the middle too.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need first to offer a description of the trap. For example, if this trap is just a deep potential well at a significant distance from the minimum of the initial potential, then the electron can indeed tunnel into the trap, but if the minimum of the trap well is below the minimum of the initial potential, the energy conservation will not be violated. If, however, the minimum of the trap is too high, the electron just will not tunnel there.

Comment: Well, WF is a complex amplitude of probability. How do we measure probability? We place a trap. A trap is a shutter-like device - it's unseen and unfelt unless the shutter closes. And when the shutter closes - the particle is either in or out. So we close the shutter and find our particle trapped. Violation of energy? Does it follow that closing the trap is not an energy free process? And if so, closeing the trap interfears with the particle state, pum;ing it with energy? Then what do we mean by saying probability density amplitude for WF?

Comment: @msk34 : Again, until you describe the design of your trap, it is difficult to discuss potential violation of energy conservation. "Shutter-like" does not explain much.The trap can indeed supply energy to the process. As for "what do we mean by saying probability density amplitude for WF?", I guess this is interpretation-dependent, so this is a long story:-)

Comment: Thank you. I guess if shutter is fast enouph to cut the WF like a scissors a mass particle will probably not have enouph time to escape the trap volume, rendering correct probability density. However the WF itself may adjust its shape with a beat appearing inside the trap volume and correstponding beat energy supplied by the shutter.